# Fatal error when ini memory exceeds the quoted error

Tags: php, zend-framework

I get this error when trying to load my index page.

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 158037 bytes)  in model/customException.php on line 21.

I have tried changing the memory limit in the ini to everything and it's uncle but I continue to get the same error and the same allowed memory size of 256mb so I'm not sure what is causing it

Comment: Clearly, it's not Uncle - whatever that means. Did you restart the server after making changes to the .ini?

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I did, the numbers seem fairly specific which makes me wonder if it's something else causing the error. If there was a list of "common things that cause this error" it would be perfect, as it stands I am working through every instance of the custom exception and seeing if there is anything wrong with them. I'm past the point where I think the php settings are incorrect.

Comment: Did you changed the `memory_limit` to `-1` or other? In what value did you changed it? Did you _restarted_ the apache as well? What the `ini_get("memory_limit");` says after?

Comment: If it isn't your server, are you sure that someone isn't over-riding what you put in? There are a lot of hosted servers that will severly limit the resources you have access to.

Comment: Try this in the begining of your script ini_set('memory_limit','512M');

Comment: I'm getting the error on my localhost, building it in dev then pushing to production.
Adding the ini_set line produced the values 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 227173 bytes) Would perhaps pushing the value up until I see a change be a valid strategy?

Comment: You need not to worry as by setting `-1` the memory limit will use all the available memory. You need to worry if you upload the script on other servers and have to do with their allowed memory pool.

Comment: I tried the -1 setting and it just resulted in the pc crashing and burning, Looks like I've accidentally hidden a fork bomb or an infinite loop somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, the totally bizarre error was caused by a type-o in the xml config. Great error hinting there, but if it happens again at least I'll know what to expect!